Is $x^my^n+x^py^q+1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

I am trying to prove that the bivariate polynomial $ x^m y^n + x^p y^q+ 1 $ is irreducible in $ \mathbb{C}[x, y] $, where $ m, n, p, q \in \mathbb{Z}_+ $, $m$ is coprime to $p$ , $n$ is coprime to $q$ , and $mq-np\neq 0$.

For special cases of the question (such as $m=n=1,p=2,q=3$), we can directly use exhaustive search and the method of undetermined coefficients to determine its irreducibility. However, for the general case, the method of undetermined coefficients no longer works.
How can we solve this problem, or are there any relevant papers that could be valuable for reference?
Thank you so much!

Pick $m=p, n=q$, gcd$(m,n)=1$, and the larger coefficient odd. Then the corresponding polynomial is never irreducible. Simply because we can write it as a univariate polynomial in $xy$ with odd degree (which never is irreducible).

@SeverinSchraven You mean $m = n$, $p = q$, and the degree parity is irrelevant since we factor over $\Bbb C$ :-)

@Amateur_Algebraist Ahh yes, I thought we were over the reals. Of course, I got the equalities wrong :(

Not really that relevant but the condition $(m-p)^2+(n-q)^2\ne 0$ is unnecessary. This is true iff $m=p$ and $n=q$, but then $mq - np = 0$ which is already disallowed.

@Philip Speegle  How to prove the irreducibility of this polynomial when $mq-np\neq0$? Can you please provide some proof ideas or related papers? Thank you very much!

Easy counterexample to the original question (without the condition $mq-np\not =0$). It shows that such polynomials can be reducible even over $\Bbb Z$:
$$x^5 y^5 + xy + 1 = (x^3y^3 - x^2y^2 + 1)(x^2y^2 + xy + 1)$$
(thanks, Sage! I just generated the tuples of coefficients using list(Tuples(range(1,10),4)), filtered them and then factor()'ed the polynomials over the symbolic ring SR. No thinking was required. Now if $mq-np = 0$, by @SeverinSchraven's observation the polynomial in question would be a univariate polynomial in disguise, thus always reducible.)

Corollary 3.18 here looks interesting...

I am not good at using Sage, so could you perhaps elaborate how you use Sage to find $x^5 y^5 + xy + 1$?

@Amateur_Algebraist Sorry, it was my negligence. This question requires additional conditions $mq-np \neq 0$. I have added this condition to the question.
